# Using AJAX to insert a partial form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form

I'm doing a complex and heavy form in my app. So to increase the performance, I would like to inject some part of this form with an AJAX method. But I cannot succeed it.

To illustrate it, I made this simple example =

**new_event (view) :**

```
<%= simple_form_for event, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.input_field :start_at %>
    <div class="">

    </div>
    <a href="/event_add_user?form=<%=f%>" class="btn" data-method="patch" data-remote="true">
        Add user to event
    </a>
    <div class="form_area"></div>
<% end %>
```

**event_controller (controller) :**

```
def add_user
    @form = params[:form]
    respond_to do |format|
       format.js {render 'add_user'}
    end
end
```

**add_user.js.erb (js file) :**

```
$('#event_form_area').append('<%=  j render partial: "events/user", locals: {f: @form} %>');
```

**user (partial) :**

```
<%= f.input_field :user_name %>
```

Currently, I have this error :

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `input' for "":String)

Comment: `href="/event_add_user?form=<%= event%>"` can you  test it with following changes.=?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're trying to pass the entire form builder `f` through params, which I don't think it's possible.

Since `f.input_field` is just a helper method to output some HTML, an idea would be to implement directly that HTML into the partial.

so, the "events/user" partial would be:

```
<input class="string required" id="event_user" maxlength="100" name="event[user]" type="text" value="" />
```

if this works, you can remove `@form = params[:form]` from the controller, the `locals` hash from the view and the `?form=<%=f%>` from the AJAX call since aren't needed anymore.

[input_field reference at rubydoc](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:input_field)

You can also use [form_tag helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#other-helpers-of-interest) too:

```
<%= text_field_tag(:event,:user) %>
```

Comment: Thnaks @Getu, that's exactly what i'm looking for. Good continuation !!

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `@form` as `f` in your partial view. Most likely, `params[:form]` is a string. Here are some of the ways to approach this problem.

**1. Recreate form object**

Since you don't have `f` object from your previous request, you can recreate it to generate an html snippet. Instead of retrieving form object from `params` which I think is impossible, you can create a new form object using a new `Event` object. I haven't tested this in rails but this should give you the idea.

```
def add_user
  @event = Event.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render 'add_user'}
  end
end
```

**Set `@user` as locals**

```
$('#event_form_area').append('<%=  j render partial: "events/user", locals: {event: @event} %>');
```

**Then recreate the form object**

```
# partial
<% form_for event do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :user_name %>
<% end %>
```

Notice the usage of `<%` instead of `<%=` on the first line. We don't want to have another `<form>` element.

Then, you're done. This code should generate html snippets

or
**2. Use plain html**

In your partial, rewrite your code to a plain html element. For example

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="event[user_name]" id="event_user_name">
```